# Why does printer crop image?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing

I have Canon LBP3200 and HP Deskjet 2300. There is a JPG looking like this:

[Original JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmwWy.jpg)

When I print it with any of those printers its bottom is cropped something like this:

[Printed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8190.jpg)

(the bottom margin varies from copy to copy)

I tried to print JPG directly from Eye Of Mate, from GIMP, tried to make a PDF from it and then print the PDF, used `lp image.jpg`, tried to resize an image (tried 520x680 and 2408x3508) but the result is the same.

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the correct paper set (such as A4, not US for example)?

Comment: If you open the PRINTERS folder; right-click in turn on the icon for each printer; if you select PROPERTIES; then MAKE & MODEL for each; can you copy what is in each entry; and paste the two results back here please: (I am thinking the LBP3200 would need the CAPT driver?)

Comment: @Graham, yes, I double-check it, it is always A4. The fact is that the bottom margin varies from copy to copy. The printer may print 2/3 of the image on first try and print most of it on second try.

Comment: @pdc, where is the PRINTERS folder? Also I have installed the CAPT driver from Canon.

Comment: @makofuhag You'll find Printers in System Settings

Comment: I have MATE. And it looks like some GUI plugins are removed, I can not find printers anywhere. There is a web interface at http://localhost:631, though.